# How to run native JavaScript function in R?

Tags: javascript, r, highcharts, nativescript, treemap

I have a native JavaScript function mentioned below which i want to run in R.

JavaScript function:

```
  $('.btn')
.click(function () {
        var from = parseInt($('.from')[0].value)
            , to = parseInt($('.to')[0].value)
            , newData = [];
        if (!isNaN(from) && !isNaN(to)) {
            Highcharts.each(data, function (p) {
                if (p.value >= from && p.value <= to) {
                    newData.push(p);
                }
            });

            }
          })
```

I want to bind this function in my Main R script where i am creating High chart Treemap function using shiny.

Main R Highchart Treemap function:

```
hc<-highchart() %>% 

    hc_title(text = "Costcenter Deviation between Quarters (A-B)") %>%
    #hc_subtitle(text="Q1 and Q2 is default selection")%>%
    hc_colorAxis( stops = colstops, endOnTick=FALSE,startOnTick=FALSE)  %>%
     #hc_colorAxis( minColor = '#1a9641', maxColor= '#a6d96a')  %>%
    hc_add_series(
      type = "treemap",
      layoutAlgorithm = "squarified",
      allowDrillToNode = T,
      dataLabels= list(enabled= F), levelIsConstant= F,


      levels =list( 
        list(
          level = 1,
          dataLabels = list(
            enabled = TRUE
          ),
          borderWidth = 3, borderColor= 'black'

        )
      ),

      data= list_data
    ) %>% 
    hc_tooltip(pointFormat = "<b>{point.name}</b>
               <br>EUR: {point.actualvalue:,.2f}</br> <br> Change:{point.change}% </br>",borderWidth=1, shared= F, followPointer=F , enabled=T, borderRadius=5) %>%
    hc_plotOptions(borderWidth=15,borderColor='#fdae61', animationLimit=1000,turboThreshold=5000)

  hc
```

SO, Is there any possible way to achieve this?

Comment: Do some research on `htmlwidgets`. But, there are already two Highcharts htmlwidgets packages for R : http://jkunst.com/r/presenting-highcharter/ & https://github.com/jcizel/highchartR

Comment: @hrbrmstr : i am already using  highcharter (jkunst) in my main R script for treemap.   But for  "('.btn').click(function()"   function  in above script, i am not able to find equivalent of it in R so i want to directly use it in my main  script.

Comment: You really need to rephrase and add more detail to your question.

Comment: @hrbrmstr : I have added more details and also the main Highchart treemap function where i want it to bind so that i can create range selection option.

Comment: `?htmlwidgets::onRender` might do what you want, or perhaps https://github.com/daattali/shinyjs

Comment: @timelyportfolio : Can you please provide me an example on  how to bind javascript  function with my R function using htmlwidgets::onRender ?. I tried but I am not able to bind it properly.

Answer (score 1):

Since you have not provided a fully reproducible example with data, I cannot help all that much.  However, I have posted some sample code that hopefully will get you started.

```
library("highcharter")
library("treemap")
library("viridis")
library("htmlwidgets")

data(GNI2014)
head(GNI2014)

tm <- treemap(GNI2014, index = c("continent", "iso3"),
              vSize = "population", vColor = "GNI",
              type = "comp", palette = rev(viridis(6)),
              draw = FALSE)

htm <- highchart(height = 800) %>% 
  hc_add_series_treemap(tm, allowDrillToNode = TRUE,
                        layoutAlgorithm = "squarified",
                        name = "tmdata") %>% 
  hc_title(text = "Gross National Income World Data") %>% 
  hc_tooltip(pointFormat = "<b>{point.name}</b>:<br>
             Pop: {point.value:,.0f}<br>
             GNI: {point.valuecolor:,.0f}")


onRender(
  htm,
"
function(el,x){
  // el will be the dom element container for our htmlwidget
  // x will be the data and options

  // uncomment the below line if you want to break in
  //  in your browser devtools
  // debugger;
 $('.btn').click(function () {
    var from = parseInt($('.from')[0].value),
      to = parseInt($('.to')[0].value),
      newData = [];
    if (!isNaN(from) && !isNaN(to)) {
      Highcharts.each(data, function (p) {
        if (p.value >= from && p.value <= to) {
          newData.push(p);
        }
      });
    }
  })
}
"
)
```